# Save XML from textarea into an xml file?

Tags: php, xml

I have a textarea in which I prints all my xml like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea id="codeTextarea" name="thisxml" cols="100" rows="36">
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <game id="103478">
    <opponent>Peter</opponent>
    <oppid>4</oppid>
    <lastdraw>0</lastdraw>
  </game>
  <game id="103479">
    <opponent>Peter</opponent>
    <oppid>4</oppid>
    <lastdraw>2</lastdraw>
  </game>
  <game id="103483">
    <opponent>James</opponent>
    <oppid>47</oppid>
    <lastdraw>2</lastdraw>
  </game>
</data>');

echo htmlspecialchars($xml->saveXML()); 
?>
</textarea>
```

I then on submit want to create/update the file with the new xml but all I get in the new xml document is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

I try to save the xml like this with PHP:

```
$myFile = 'TEST.xml';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = htmlspecialchars($_POST['thisxml']);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Are you sure, you want to save it encoded with `htmlspecialchars` and not the plain `$_POST[thisxml]` string (I mean the line `$stringData = htmlspecialchars($_POST['thisxml']);`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `htmlspecialchars($_POST['thisxml'])` would make your `XML invalid` an return something like

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;ISO-8859-1&quot;?&gt;
&lt;data&gt;
  &lt;game id=&quot;103478&quot;&gt;
    &lt;opponent&gt;Peter&lt;/opponent&gt;
    &lt;oppid&gt;4&lt;/oppid&gt;
    &lt;lastdraw&gt;0&lt;/lastdraw&gt;
  &lt;/game&gt;
  &lt;game id=&quot;103479&quot;&gt;
    &lt;opponent&gt;Peter&lt;/opponent&gt;
    &lt;oppid&gt;4&lt;/oppid&gt;
    &lt;lastdraw&gt;2&lt;/lastdraw&gt;
  &lt;/game&gt;
  &lt;game id=&quot;103483&quot;&gt;
    &lt;opponent&gt;James&lt;/opponent&gt;
    &lt;oppid&gt;47&lt;/oppid&gt;
    &lt;lastdraw&gt;2&lt;/lastdraw&gt;
  &lt;/game&gt;
&lt;/data&gt;
```

Just use `file_put_contents` it combines the functions of `fopen ,  fwrite , fclose`

```
file_put_contents('TEST.xml', $_POST['thisxml']);
```

Comment: Super, but when doing so it outcomment all " with a \ like this: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
<data>
  <game id=\"103479\">

Comment: Whe clicking on the link [php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php] I got no page? Where do I turn it off?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. Here's my comment again: That's likely due to ["Magic Quotes"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), which automatically insert a backslash to escape `'`, `"`, backslash, and `NULL` characters. You should probably turn that feature off as it is deprecated.

Comment: @JesperMansa You might want to be aware that, if you manually create the XML file (e.g. using `file_put_contents`), it is not guaranteed to be well-formed and valid. You should consider `DOMDocument::save`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save an XML file directly using [`DOMDocument::save`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

if ($xml->loadXML($_POST['thisxml']) === FALSE)
{
    die("The submitted XML is invalid");
}

if ($xml->save('TEST.xml') === FALSE)
{
    die("Can't save file");
}
```

Comment: When doing this I only get <?xml version="1.0"?> in the document?

Comment: I think it has to do with Magic Quotes. You can read about how to [Disable Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). You can also use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to manually remove slashes when you read `$_POST('thisxml')`, before loading it as XML.

Answer (score 0):

I found this script and just added it in the header and voila :-)

```
function stripslashes_array(&$array, $iterations=0) {
    if ($iterations < 3) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                stripslashes_array($array[$key], $iterations + 1);
            } else {
                $array[$key] = stripslashes($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    stripslashes_array($_GET);
    stripslashes_array($_POST);
    stripslashes_array($_COOKIE);
}
```

Thanks for your input ;-)